# Odd type struct behavior in f#

Tags: .net, visual-studio, struct, f#

So I've read that if you take a type struct from, for istance, a List you get a copy since struct are not mutable. Said so, if you want to make a change you have to replace the entire 
struct in the list. Now I've experienced a very odd behavior with the following code

```
 if pressed then
        let ret = rectangles.Item(ret_index)
        ret.Offset(loc.X - offs.Width - ret.X, loc.Y - offs.Height - ret.Y)
        rectangles.Item(ret_index) <- ret
        for i = 0 to couples.Count - 1 do
            match couples.Item(i) with
                | (idx_s, idx_e, rectf, string) when idx_s = ret_index || 
                                                     idx_e = ret_index ->
                    let mutable r = rectf
                    let x = (rectangles.Item(idx_e).X + rectangles.Item(idx_s).X) / 2
                    let y = (rectangles.Item(idx_e).Y + rectangles.Item(idx_s).Y) / 2
                    r.X <- single x
                    r.Y <- single y
                    couples.Item(i) <- (idx_s, idx_e, r, string)
```

So is bad practice to define a mutable Rectangle? (I've read mutable struct are "evil")
Now my real question: why the code above works but the following doesn't?

```
if pressed then
    let ret = rectangles.Item(ret_index)
    ret.Offset(loc.X - offs.Width - ret.X, loc.Y - offs.Height - ret.Y)
    rectangles.Item(ret_index) <- ret
    for i = 0 to couples.Count - 1 do
        match couples.Item(i) with
            | (idx_s, idx_e, rectf, string) when idx_s = ret_index || 
                                                 idx_e = ret_index ->
                let r = rectf
                let x = (rectangles.Item(idx_e).X + rectangles.Item(idx_s).X) / 2
                let y = (rectangles.Item(idx_e).Y + rectangles.Item(idx_s).Y) / 2
                r.Offset(single x - r.X, single y - r.Y)
                couples.Item(i) <- (idx_s, idx_e, r, string)
```

Comment: In one you're doing an offset. The other you are just changing x and y.

Comment: The problem is that if at the end of code i draw the rectangle, the first code works and the rectangle moves just fine, the second code does nothing. In other words the last line in the second code does not substitute the rectangle.

Comment: I'd post the entire code but it's hundreds of lines

Comment: In the first example your defining r as mutable, but not actually mutating it. Your mutating r.X and r.Y, which are properties of the rect that r is bound to. In the second example I see no reason why you couldn't do the same mutation to r (set r.X and r.Y). I've not worked with rctangles much so I may be missing something, but I think the biggest difference between the two is your use of Offset in the second version rather than changing the X and Y explicitly.